# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'print_ad_option_id'

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I have method in which I do some ajax:

```
function prodChange() {
    console.log(this.value);

    // ajax
    var url = '@Url.Action("GetAdvProdList", "Contract")' + '?prod_id=' + this.value;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        success: showAdvProd,
        error: function() {
            console.log("FAILSHAKUREHKGAHH");
        }
    });  
}
```

The ajax returns successfully and calls this controller method.

```
public ActionResult GetAdvProdList(int prod_id) { // product id
        // get advertising products for this product
        OutlookMediaEntities1 db = new OutlookMediaEntities1();

        var advsList = from printAdOption in db.print_ad_option
                        where printAdOption.print_product_id == prod_id
                        select printAdOption;

        List<SelectListItem> adv_list = new List<SelectListItem>(); // list of ads
        List<print_ad_option> advs = advsList.ToList(); // list from db
        foreach (print_ad_option av in advs)
        {
            SelectListItem temp_item = new SelectListItem();
            temp_item.Text = av.name;
            temp_item.Value = av.print_ad_option_id.ToString();
            adv_list.Add(temp_item);
        }
        ViewData["advproducts"] = new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)adv_list.ToList(), "Value", "Text");

        return null;
    }
```

I'm returning null because it doesn't work if I return View or PartialView, and I don't think I want it to return those things anyway. All I want is the viewdata stuff to be set.

The ajax worked well before I added code to use the view data. Unfortunately when I try to use the new ViewData in the ajax success method, I get this error:
"There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'print_ad_option_id'"
The thing is that I get this error when I first load the page, so it seems to be attempting to evaluate the "@Html.DropDownListFor..." before the showAdvProd function is called:

```
// called when the ajax returns a list of adv prods in a viewdata
function showAdvProd() {
    // add drop down
    $("#drdn1").append('@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.print_ad_option_id, ViewData["advproducts"] as SelectList)');
}
```

The function that does ajax is called when an item is selected from a (different) dropdown menu, but with this error the page doesn't even load, so obviously the ajax function is never called and thus the controller method never called. So of course it won't recognize the viewdata...

I'm similarly creating a dropdown menu in another part of my form, using viewdata but without ajax, and it works fine. So I think something is wrong with my ajax or my controller method, not with how I'm using the viewdata.

Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on your initial page load, the view engine will evaluate all the code blocks - anything with a '`@`' symbol in front of it. Thus it will try and look for a ViewData item called *advproducts* before it exists, even though that reference is within a javascript function that hasn't been called yet. Remember - code blocks (such as `@Html.blahblahblah()` are evaluated server side, while you are expecting your ajax to run on the client side, after the page has been sent to the client.

A couple of options: Returning a partial view should work. You could return a partialview that contains a dropdown and fill it from the ViewBag. That would look like this:

initial page:

```
...
<div id="advProductsSection"></div>
...
```

Your ajax would call the same function, but would return a partial view:

```
public ActionResult GetAdvProdList(int prod_id) { // product id
...
ViewData["advproducts"] = new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)adv_list.ToList(), "Value", "Text");
return View("_AdvProducts");
}
```

And then a partial view (Here named `_AdvProducts.cshtml`):

```
@Html.DropDownList("className", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewBag["advproducts"])
```

Your ajax function would need to change to replace the div with the new partial:

```
success: function (result) {
    $('#advProductsSection').html(result);
}
```

Or something like that..

A second alternative is to return JSON from the Action Method and populate a dropdown with that.

Your Controller:

```
...
return JSON(adv_list.ToList());
}
```

Then in your ajax success func:

```
success: function(list) {
    // states is your JSON array
    var $dropdown = $('#Dropdown');
    $.each(list, function(i, product) {
        $('<option>', {
            value: list.Value
        }).html(list.Text).appendTo($dropdown);
    });
}
```

You'd need to cleat the dropdown again when `prodchange` is called.